# What makes using an Oracle Wallet to connect to a data source more secure than using a username and password to do the same?

Tags: oracle

What makes using an Oracle Wallet to connect to a data source more secure than using a username and password to do the same? If someone knows the connection string for using an Oracle Wallet to connect to a data source, isn't this just as good as having the username and password? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

- Wallets can be configured to only be valid from a specific client, so
  access to the specific host is also required, whereas
  username/password text can be easily ported elsewhere with
  copy/paste.
- Using wallets also allows most applications to be redeployed between
  environments (like dev and prod) without requiring reconfiguration or
  changes to credentials.
- Placing the credentials in an external store allows password
  management policies to be more easily enforced without changing
  application code whenever user names or passwords change.